# Flume to stream gz files

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, flume-ng

I have a folder contains a lot of gzip files. Each gzip file contains xml file. I had used flume to stream the files into HDFS. Below is my configuration file:

```
agent1.sources = src
agent1.channels = ch
agent1.sinks = sink

agent1.sources.src.type = spooldir
agent1.sources.src.spoolDir = /home/tester/datafiles
agent1.sources.src.channels = ch
agent1.sources.src.deserializer = org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.BlobDeserializer$Builder

agent1.channels.ch.type = memory
agent1.channels.ch.capacity = 1000
agent1.channels.ch.transactionCapacity = 1000

agent1.sinks.sink.type = hdfs
agent1.sinks.sink.channel = ch
agent1.sinks.sink.hdfs.path = /user/tester/datafiles
agent1.sinks.sink.hdfs.fileType = CompressedStream
agent1.sinks.sink.hdfs.codeC = gzip
agent1.sinks.sink.hdfs.fileSuffix = .gz
agent1.sinks.sink.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
agent1.sinks.sink.hdfs.rollSize = 122000000
agent1.sinks.sink.hdfs.rollCount = 0
agent1.sinks.sink.hdfs.idleTimeout = 1
agent1.sinks.sink.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
```

After I stream the files into HDFS, i use Spark to read it using the following code:

```
df = sparkSession.read.format('com.databricks.spark.xml').options(rowTag='Panel', compression='gzip').load('/user/tester/datafiles')
```

But I am having issue to read it. If i manually upload one gzip file into HDFS folder and re-run the above Spark code, it able to read it without any issue. I am not sure is it due to flume.

I tried to download the file streamed by flume and unzip it, when i viewed the contents, it no longer showing the xml format, it is some unreadable character. Could anyone shed me some light on this? Thanks.

Comment: How do you unzip file? Using `gunzip`? And what issue to you encouter reading files with spark? Have you tried specyfing schema manually to spark-xml?

Comment: Mariusz, I didn't unzip the files. I was trying to stream in the gz files and read it using spark. I did not specify the schema manually. When i read the streamed-in gzip file and show it content, it display some special character. But when i tried to manually upload the gzip file in HDFS, i am able to read it without any issue, it can display the content and schema without any issue. I think it is due to Flume?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it **Wrong!!!** Why ?

See you are having a source which is **"Non Split-able"** ZIP . you can'read them partially as record by record,if you do not decompress you will get a GZIPInputStream, which you are getting in flume source.

And after reading that GZIP input stream as input records you are saving already ziped streams into another GZIP stream as you selected sink type as compressed.

So you have Zipped Streamed inside a Gzip in HDFS . :)

I suggest schedule a script in cron to do a copy from local to HDFS will solve your problem .

Comment: Oh i see...So there is no way for Flume to pickup the gzip file and put it into HDFS with its original format? I was thinking if i were to schedule a script in cron to do the copy from local to HDFS, then it will have many small files in HDFS. This will end up taking up many blocks in HDFS. This is because each of the gzip file size are around 20kb only.

Comment: What you can do is, you can use spark to read those zip files and after processing write it to hadoop,.